# Ubuntu Gnome and application icon in top bar?

Tags: gnome, icons, taskbar

When I install application that add icon in top bar, I don't see anything in top bar. Is GNOME shell restricts iconns? How can I change it to let application icon to be added there?

Answer (score 3):

You can use one of the following Gnome shell extentions:

- AppIndicator Support: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/615/appindicator-support/

  - only for applications with AppIndicator support (most applications for Ubuntu)
  - good Gnome shell integration
  - configure what icons to show in panel
- TopIcons: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/495/topicons/